# N-body simulation in coarray Fortran

Tags: performance, fortran

I am new to coarray Fortran and wrote a naive nbody-simulation. It is about 30x slower than an implementation in C + gasnet or C + openSHMEM.

I compiled with gfortran -O3 -march=native -mtune=native -Wall -ffast-math -fcoarray=lib -g -lcaf_openmpi using GCC 12.2.0 and Open MPI 4.1.4

```
! An n-body simulation.

module accelerateModule
contains
function accelerate(pos1, pos2, mass) result(a)
    implicit none

    real(KIND=8), intent(in) :: pos1(3), pos2(3)
    real(KIND=8), intent(in) :: mass
    real(KIND=8) :: norm
    real(KIND=8) :: a(3)

    norm = sum((pos2 - pos1)**2)**1.5

    if (norm .eq. 0) then
        a = 0
    else
        a = (pos2 - pos1) * mass / norm
    end if
end function accelerate

subroutine accelerateAll(accel, positions, masses, n)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(KIND=8) :: positions(3, n / num_images())[*]
    real(KIND=8) :: accel(3, n / num_images())[*]
    real(KIND=8) :: masses(n / num_images())[*]

    integer :: blockFactor, i, j, s
    integer :: I1, J1

    blockFactor = 100

    accel(:,:) = 0

    ! Unblocked
!    do s = 1, num_images()
!        do i = 1, n / num_images()
!            do j = 1, n / num_images()
!                accel(:,i) = accel(:,i) + &
!                                 accelerate(positions(:,i), positions(:,j)[s], masses(j)[s])
!            end do
!        end do
!    end do

    ! blocked
    do s = 1, num_images()
        do I1 = 1, n / num_images(), blockFactor
            do J1 = 1, n / num_images(), blockFactor
        do i = I1, MIN(I1 + blockFactor, n / num_images())
            ! Calculate acceleration with respect to processor s
            do j = J1, MIN(J1 + blockFactor, n / num_images())
                    accel(:,i) = accel(:,i) + &
                                 accelerate(positions(:,i), positions(:,j)[s], masses(j)[s])
            end do
        end do
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine accelerateAll
end module accelerateModule


module nbodyModule
contains
subroutine advanceIt(positions, velocities, masses, accel, dt, n)
    use accelerateModule
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(KIND=8), intent(in) :: dt
    real(KIND=8) :: masses(n / num_images())[*]
    real(KIND=8) :: positions(3, n / num_images())[*], velocities(3, n / num_images())[*]
    real(KIND=8) :: accel(3, n / num_images())[*]

    call accelerateAll(accel, positions, masses, n)
    velocities = velocities + accel * dt
    positions = velocities * dt
    sync all

end subroutine advanceIt
end module nbodyModule

program main
    use nbodyModule
    implicit none

    integer :: n, iterations, p, t
    real(KIND=8), dimension(:,:), codimension[:], allocatable :: positions, velocities, accel
    real(KIND=8), dimension(:), codimension[:], allocatable :: masses
    real(KIND=8) :: dt
    integer :: cpu_count, cpu_count2, count_rate, count_max
    character(len=12), dimension(:), allocatable :: args

    allocate(args(2))
    call get_command_argument(1, args(1))
    read (unit=args(1), fmt=*) n

    call get_command_argument(2, args(2))
    read (unit=args(2), fmt=*) iterations

    p = num_images()

    if (modulo(n, p) /= 0) then
        write (*, *) 'Please make sure n divides p'
    end if

    allocate(positions(3, n / p)[*])
    allocate(velocities(3, n / p)[*])
    allocate(accel(3, n / p)[*])
    allocate(masses(n / p)[*])

    positions = 1
    masses = 1
    velocities = 0

    dt = 0.1

    sync all
    call system_clock(cpu_count, count_rate, count_max)

    do t = 1, iterations
        call advanceIt(positions, velocities, masses, accel, dt, n)
    end do

    sync all

    call system_clock(cpu_count2, count_rate, count_max)

    if (this_image() .eq. 1) then
        write (*, *) 3.0 * 16.0 * n * n * iterations / 1000000000.0 / &
            (real(cpu_count2 - cpu_count) / count_rate)
    end if
end program main
```

On a shared memory machine with 6 cores, avx2 and fma instructions, 6000 bodies, 2 iterations in Gflops/s

```
Cores | Fortran | C + gasnet
1          -       5.019309 
2    0.266810775   8.184725
4    0.451116025   13.370887
6    0.569451332   18.508898
```

Comment: Could you also post the corresponding C code to ensure apples are compared with apples.

Comment: You can try OpenMP by adding comments, but maybe I am missing the point of the `num_image` variable/function that I dont see in your post. Also can you add details about you numerical scheme (Time scheme, numerical method that you use, neighboring list if relevant, etc)?